# Get information from Firebase and able to use it with a Gridtile and GestureDetector in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to design a Widget which can basically create a view where you can have something like this:

[image]

The problem that I'm facing is that for this example I used is calls to API's of Firebase, however, now I'm using the Firebase Auth and Firestore Extentionts and don't want to use the provider package or HTTP request, I have the following Firestore Collection:

[image]

As you see the collection name is users but inside has the user uid given by Firebase as a Document and inside that document has all the user Data.

So I need some help to have the following functionalities:

1. I need to create a ListView preferably ListView Builder so it can show the entire collection so it can display all the users contained in the collection. (Each user is a Document titled with his own User uid).
2. In the Tile, I want to display just name and Image but once it is clickable it should send me to a new page (the user profile page sending as an argument the uid)

I got this code: **but I don't have the logic on how to get the list tile clickable and get the uid of the click user (in the tile) to send the info (uid) to the next page.** But once I know how to display the contents of all the documents in the collection (displaying the name (nombre) inside each document as a title and how to capture the uid, I bet I can do the modifications and eliminations.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_firestore/firebase_firestore.dart';

class ExpenseList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text("No existe registros de Usuario");
          return new ListView(children: getExpenseItems(snapshot));
        });
  }

  getExpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents
        .map((doc) => ListTile(title: new Text(doc["nombre"], onTap: (){
//Here function to navigate to profile page saving the uid
}))
            .toList();
      }
    }
```

In that list tile, I should have a Network image as I can have a parameter the image from the document in the collection.

Is there anything I can do?

Kind Regards.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Anurag26/components/blob/93a65bef4dc9f33c3d7397eaf094640f77c5958b/lib/widgets/RecipeList.dart) you can find an example of a custom build ListView. I found this example on [this guide](https://hackernoon.com/creating-a-custom-listview-using-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-flutter-j02xw3w6z) and I think that it can be usefull for you. Also, you have multiple questions and points (how to create a listview builder, clickable tiles, if you should use network images). Please. make your question more focused and stick to one issue per question.

Comment: If your issue is how to make a ListView tile clickable you can use the [GestureDetector class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to wrap your tile and send the UID in the .OnTap event. You can achieve this by including the gesture detector inside of your tile

Comment: Hey that was exactly what I need it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Anurag26/components/blob/93a65bef4dc9f33c3d7397eaf094640f77c5958b/lib/widgets/RecipeList.dart) you can find an example of a custom build ListView.

```
var futureBuilder=new FutureBuilder(
      future: makecall.firebaseCalls(databaseReference), // async work
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none: return new Text('Press button to start');
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading....');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
                return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                   return Card(
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child:  SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.15,
                       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                       child:  Card(
                           elevation: 0,
                           child: Row(
                             children: <Widget>[
                               new Container(
                                     child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].iconUrl,height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3,width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3,),
                               ),
                               Padding(
                                 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,right: 5,top: 5),
                                 child: Column(
                                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                   children: <Widget>[
                                     new Container(
                                       child: Column(
                                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                         children: <Widget>[
                                           Column(
                                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                             children: <Widget>[
                                               Row(
                                                 children: <Widget>[
                                                   condition('${snapshot.data[index].vegOrNon}')==true? new Image.asset('images/non_veg.png',height: 15,width: 15,): new Image.asset('images/veg.jpg',height: 15,width: 15),
                                                   SizedBox(width: 5),
                                                   Text(snapshot.data[index].foodtitle, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20,fontFamily: 'Roboto-Black'),)
                                                 ],
                                               ),

                                               SizedBox(height:10.0),
                                               Row(
                                                 children: <Widget>[
                                                   new IconTheme(
                                                     data: new IconThemeData(
                                                         color: Colors.black26),
                                                     child: new Icon(Icons.timer,size: 20.0,),
                                                   ),
                                                   Text('${snapshot.data[index].PreptimeInMins} minutes',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,color: Colors.black26),),
                                                 ],
                                               ),
                                             ],
                                           )
                                         ],
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                   ],
                                 ),
                               ),

                             ],
                           )
                       )


                   ),
                ),
              );
                },
                );
        }
      },
    );
```

I found this example on [this guide](https://hackernoon.com/creating-a-custom-listview-using-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-flutter-j02xw3w6z) and I think that it can be usefull for you.

If your issue is how to make a ListView tile clickable you can use the [GestureDetector class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to wrap your tile and send the UID in the .OnTap event